# How to share group_vars between different inventories in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

The Ansible best practices documentation [recommends](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) to separate inventories:

```
inventories/
   production/
      hosts.ini           # inventory file for production servers
      group_vars/
         group1           # here we assign variables to particular groups
         group2           # ""
      host_vars/
         hostname1        # if systems need specific variables, put them here
         hostname2        # ""

   staging/
      hosts.ini           # inventory file for staging environment
      group_vars/
         group1           # here we assign variables to particular groups
         group2           # ""
      host_vars/
         stagehost1       # if systems need specific variables, put them here
         stagehost2       # ""
```

My staging and production environments are structured in the same way. I have in both environments the same groups. And it turns out that I have also the same group_vars for the same groups. This means redundancy I would like to wipe out.

Is there a way to share some group_vars between different inventories?

As a work-around I started to put shared group_vars into the roles.

```
my_var:
  my_group:
    - { var1: 1, var2: 2 }
```

This makes it possible to iterate over some vars by intersecting the groups of a host with the defined var:

```
with_items: "{{group_names | intersect(my_var.keys())}}"
```

But this is a bit complicate to understand and I think roles should not know anything about groups.

I would like to separate most of the inventories but share some of the group_vars in an easy to understand way.  Is it possible to merge global group_vars with inventory specific group_vars?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I scrapped the idea of following Ansible's recommendation. Now one year later, I am convinced that Ansible's recommendation is not useful for my requirements. Instead I think it is important to share as much as possible among different stages.

Now I put all inventories in the same directory:

```
production.ini
reference.ini
```

And I take care that each inventory defines a group including all hosts with the name of the stage.

The file `production.ini` has the group `production`:

```
[production:children]
all_production_hosts
```

And the file `reference.ini` has the group `reference`:

```
[reference:children]
all_reference_hosts
```

I have just one `group_vars` directory in which I define a file for every staging group:

```
group_vars/production.yml
group_vars/reference.yml
```

And each file defines a `stage` variable. The file `production.yml` defines this:

```
---
stage: production
```

And the file `reference.yml` defines that:

```
---
stage: reference
```

This makes it possible to share everything else between production and reference. But the hosts are completely different. By using the right inventory the playbook runs either on production or on reference hosts:

```
ansible-playbook -i production.ini site.yml
ansible-playbook -i reference.ini site.yml
```

If it is necessary for the `site.yml` or the roles to behave slightly different in the production and reference environment, they can use conditions using the `stage` variable. But I try to avoid even that. Because it is better to move all differences into equivalent definitions in the staging files `production.yml` and `reference.yml`.

For example, if the `group_vars/all.yml` defines some users:

```
users:
  - alice
  - bob
  - mallory
```

And I want to create the users in both environments, but I want to exclude `mallory` from the production environment, I can define a new group called `effective_users`. In the `reference.yml` it is identical to the `users` list:

```
effective_users: >-
  {{ users }}
```

But in the `production.yml` I can exclude `mallory`:

```
effective_users: >-
  {{ users | difference(['mallory']) }}
```

The playbook or the roles do not need to distinguish between the two stages, they can simply use the group `effective_users`. The group contains automatically the right list of users simply by selecting the inventory.

Comment: I started using Ansible ignoring the recommended way for inventories, and using a single inventory, separating environments by groups (i.e. 'production' group, 'staging' group, etc.), which was way more practical than the split inventories scheme. But right now I am (a bit frustratedly) migrating to the recommended scheme, simply because it is the way other people expect it, and makes communication and exchange of roles and etc. easier...

Comment: I have always gone with a single inventory directory, and one inventory file per environment (like your setup here).  This makes it very easy to share `group_vars/all.yml`, which seems important to avoid non-environment-related parameters being copied or symbolic-linked between environments.

Comment: You can also use this single directory + group hierarchy model to share additional `group_vars` files across environments  (e.g. `dbserver.yml`), while other group_vars are environment specific) (e.g. `dbserver-staging`) - useful for cases like different memory size in production vs. staging, but only for DB servers.

Answer (score 8):

The simple option here (and what we do) is simply symlink generic group vars files around.

For instance we might have a generic role for something like NGINX and then a few concrete use cases for that role. In this case we create a group vars file that uses the NGINX role for each concrete use case and then simply symlink those group vars files into the appropriate folders.

Our project folder structure then might look something like this (drastically simplified):

```
.
├── inventories
│   ├── bar-dev
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── bar.yml -> ../../shared/bar.yml
│   │   │   └── dev.yml -> ../../shared/dev.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── bar-prod
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── bar.yml -> ../../shared/bar.yml
│   │   │   └── prod.yml -> ../../shared/prod.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── bar-test
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── bar.yml -> ../../shared/bar.yml
│   │   │   └── test.yml -> ../../shared/test.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── foo-dev
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── dev.yml -> ../../shared/dev.yml
│   │   │   └── foo.yml -> ../../shared/foo.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── foo-prod
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── foo.yml -> ../../shared/foo.yml
│   │   │   └── prod.yml -> ../../shared/prod.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── foo-test
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── foo.yml -> ../../shared/foo.yml
│   │   │   └── test.yml -> ../../shared/test.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   └── shared
│       ├── bar.yml
│       ├── dev.yml
│       ├── foo.yml
│       ├── prod.yml
│       └── test.yml
└── roles
    └── nginx
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── meta
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            └── main.yml
```

Now our inventory files can have the hosts use these shared group vars simply by putting the hosts in the correct groups.

Comment: Nice to see, that I am not the only one with this problem.

Comment: BTW: I have to use Fossil SCM and Fossil's default is to follow symlinks. This is done in order to avoid Windows problems by generating Unix problems. The Fossil guys probably think that Unix problems are easier to solve than Windows problems. So I am not sure if the symlinks are an option for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can place `group_vars` in playbook directory as well. [More info](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Ansible will pick them up for all inventories.

Comment: But this works only for playbooks. Ad-hoc commands will fail. Is there a way to customize ad-hoc command execution so that global group_vars are read?

Comment: Another problem seems to be, that I have to set `hash_behaviour = merge`, if I want to collect a variable from different groups. And how about array values in hashes?

Comment: This will not work with ad-hoc. Lists can't be auto-merged, you have to use some manual tasks for that.

Comment: whats the definition of "adhoc commands"? those aren't ansible coammands instead of ansible-playbook, correct? as the ansible and ansible-playbook read the group_vars for me