# Ansible | How to inherit variables in inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have inventory:

```
[machine]
192.168.1.2

[group1:children]
machine

[group2:children]
machine

[group3:children]
machine

[group1:vars]
my_var="DOG"

[group2:vars]
my_var="CAT"

[group3:vars]
my_var="FISH"
```

When I run `ansible -m debug -a "var=my_var" {group1 or group2 or group3 or machine}` I always get `my_var="FISH"` because `machine` host inherits variable from the last group in file. How can I pass my_var value depending on the calling a specific parent group (group1, group2, group3)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share group\_vars between different inventories in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606890/how-to-share-group-vars-between-different-inventories-in-ansible)

Comment: You can't.  Your host belongs to all those groups, no matter which group you cite on the command line, and so it gets its variables from those groups when the inventory file is processed, which happens before ansible does any other processing.

Comment: You also may take advantage from [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).